# $\frac 12 + \frac 34 +\frac 56 +\cdots$ up to $n$ terms is equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

OK,I need to sum summation of this

> $\dfrac 12 + \dfrac 34 +\dfrac 56 +\cdots$ up to $n$ terms $=?$

I came up till here…

$$\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}\dfrac{2k-1}{2k}=?$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} 1 - \dfrac{1}{2k}=?$$

But from here I couldn't complete,please help.

Comment: You are summing from $n=1$ to $n=n$ of a function of $n$. I'm guessing what you meant to write is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2k - 1}{2k}$$

Comment: @Mattos edited.

Comment: Well....There is no closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$

Comment: Best you can do is to write it in terms of the [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Hint : The sum $$H_k:=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}$$ is called the $k$-th Harmonic number. For large $k$; we have $H_k\approx \ln(k)+\frac{1}{2k}+\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Macheroni-constant. If $k$ is small, just sum up the terms.

Comment: @Peter I don't want a number,I want expression in terms of $n$, like how it will be in mathematical induction.

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want :
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2i-1}{2i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(1 - \frac{1}{2i}\right) = n -\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1i
$$
However the harmonic sum doesn't have a closed form. You have however several bounds on it. A simple one is :
$$
\ln(n+1) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1i \leq \ln(n) + 1
$$
You can therefore bound your sum by :
$$
n - \frac12(\ln(n)+1) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2i-1}{2i} \leq n-\frac12\ln(n+1)
$$

Comment: Oh yeah thank's for the edit. I mixed the indices...

Comment: Can this summation be written in closed form in terms on n? (Without inequality and logarithm)

Comment: You can express [harmonic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) using digamma function.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, we cannot reduce your sum into closed form in terms of elementary functions.  We can, however, deduce that

$$S=n-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$

The last remaining sum is known as the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), so

$$S=n-\frac12H_n$$

By using the integral test, we know that

$$\ln(n+1)<H_n<\ln(n)+1$$

By using the [Euler-Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), we know that

$$H_n=\gamma+\ln(n)+\frac1{2n}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2k}}{2kn^{2k}}\tag{$\star$}$$

where $B_k$ are [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).  By recalling the geometric series, we find that

$$\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$

By integrating both sides from zero to one, we find that

$$H_n=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\ dx\tag{$\star$}$$

By letting $x\mapsto1-x$, applying binomial expansion, and integrating term by term, we find that

$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\frac1k\binom nk\tag{$\star'$}$$

By recalling that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$, where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), we find that

$$\ln(\Gamma(x+1))=\ln(x)+\ln(\Gamma(x))$$

By differentiating both sides, we end up with the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function):

$$\psi(x+1)=\frac1x+\psi(x)$$

Which satisfies the recurrence formula for the harmonic numbers:

$$H_n=\frac1n+H_{n-1}$$

Thus, we deduce that

$$H_n=\gamma+\psi(n+1)\tag{$\star$}$$

By directly differentiating the integral form of the Gamma function, we find that

$$\psi(x)=\cfrac{\int_0^\infty\ln(t)t^xe^{-t}\ dt}{\int_0^\infty t^xe^{-t}\ dt}$$

But the moral of the story is that

$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$

is probably the closest thing to a closed form for you.

---

As a side note, the $\star$-ed points allow you to extend the harmonic numbers analytically to non-integer and even non-real values.  The only exception being $\star'$, which must be altered slightly:

$$H_x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k\binom xk$$

where we used [generalized binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem):

$$\binom xk=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-k+1)}{k!}$$

One also finds that by [Euler sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation)ming this last sum, we get

$$H_x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\binom nk\binom x{k+1}$$

which converges faster.

Comment: Hm, all the "we find that" sounds annoying, doesn't it?

Comment: Hehe,not really,but I don't know most of these topics.

Comment: @Noddy yes, this sum of yours is rather complicated.  When I have time, I don't mind explaining the basics to some of these, like the $\int$ symbol.